# why cannot i write console.log in a primary function

Tags: javascript

```
let spiderman = function(callFunction){
   let hulk = "have a great day" 
   callFunction(hulk);
};

spiderman( function(hulk){
   console.log(`My name is Ryu and you ${hulk}`);
});
```

In the code above, i am implementing the call back function, and it works however when i insert console.log in the statement "have a great day", The hulk variable becomes undefined. I need to know why its gets undefined.
   The code below shows errors in console.

```
let spiderman = function(callFunction){
   let hulk = console.log("have a great day"); 
   callFunction(hulk);
};


spiderman( function(hulk){
   console.log(`My name is Ryu and you ${hulk}`);
});
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. And a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it). Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers. Happy coding!

Comment: console.log() doesnt return anything. Its undefined ( like void if you know C or derived C# or Java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `hulk` is undefined when you write:

```
let hulk = console.log("have a great day");
```

...is because you're assigning it the *return value* of `console.log("have a great day")`. Because `console.log` doesn't return anything, `hulk` gets assigned the value `undefined`. You can't assign it a string value and do a console log all in one statement. Rather, you can do something like this instead:

```
let hulk = "have a great day";
console.log(hulk);
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `console.log` is *always* `undefined` (by definition).